# "JSON_PARSING_ERROR" en PHP al intentar hacer una petición post al servidor de firebase cloud messaging

Tags: php, json, firebase, fcm

He intentado mil formas de hacer el post con php a la api de `firebase cloud messaging`, y siempre recibo un error:

> JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.\n

Aquí adjunto el código:

```php
$json_data = array(
                "to" => $mobileToken,
                "notification" => array(
                    "title" => "¡Hoy toca entrenar!",
                    "body" => "Consulta aquí el plan de hoy, Runneante."
                )
            );
            $data = json_encode($json_data);
            $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
            $server_key = 'XXXXX no la muestrp';
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type:application/json',
                'Authorization:key='.$server_key
            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }
            curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: no entiendo de donde sale ese error de tu php o lo revuelve el firebase???

Comment: y para poder solucionar eso creo que debes mostrar el contenido completo del codigo ...